# ML Kit Text Recognition/Automatic Rotation

Tags: google-mlkit

The text recognition in ML Kit works well IF the orientation of the image is correct(not rotated 90 degrees or upside down).   All common OCR engines have an auto orientation function to automatically determine the orientation before performing the text recognition.  I do not see anything in the documentation that states there's a flag that can be set to perform auto orientation.   Does it exist in MK Kit?

I also see a TextRecognizerOptions class but no documentation on how to set the options.  I assume there are options to be set here(like look for "english", etc.).  Where is the detailed documentation on this class?

Answer (score 0):

ML Kit OCR supports latin languages. We do not provide options to specify interested languages, and in the return type, it contains the [detected languages](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/text/Text.Element#getRecognizedLanguage()).

For image rotation, the current OCR can only handle the up-right image, but ML Kit can handle the image rotation for you with the given image orientation information. For example, with the bitmap input, you need to provide the [image orientation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/common/InputImage#fromBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int)), so that ML Kit could rotate the image for you and run the detection.